# Increase reponse size limit in sharepoint cross-domain library

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

As mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp179895.aspx), `the response-size expected shouldn't be more than 200 kb` when using the cross-domain library with web proxy. Is it possible to increase this limit?

I am trying to build a `sharepoint-hosted` application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this for O365 then you have to go for workaround. It is not editable in SPO but can be hacked on on-prem.

> There are several ways you can access remote web services in your app,
>   if your app is entirely hosted in SharePoint, you can use JSONP, CORS
>   or XDR if the external server supports either of these. Alternatively
>   you can use WebProxy. Or, if you are trying to access an structured
>   data source you can also create an app scoped BDC model (here is a
>   sample you might find useful
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/jj163088(v=office.15).aspx)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/73cda35c-df16-4dbe-a69f-1286c32252b4/query-a-remote-service-using-the-web-proxy-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=appsforsharepoint

or also check this:

[SP.WebRequestInfo 403 The Size of reponse from the remote endpoint exceeds](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118198/sp-webrequestinfo-403-the-size-of-reponse-from-the-remote-endpoint-exceeds)

Comment: I had checked all of the above mentioned links but none of them answers the OP. I want to increase the _response-size_ limit. If it is impossible, fine. But I am afraid there can be no workarounds.